# browser not opening in client side using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open `Chrome` on the client side using `selenium webdriver`. I have a piece of code and it works fine for single system, but I can't access it in another system.

I am using `selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar`, `chromedriver` for the purpose.

This is the code I use to open browser:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the ChromeDriver on the other system in the same place as on the single system?

Try something like the following (in java):

```
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String chromeDriverLocation = currentDir + "/../tools/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("disable-plugins");
    options.addArguments("disable-extensions");

    WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);

    chrome.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: No.Now i  have chromedriver.exe and it is placed in server, bin folder of apache tomcat.while accessing using my app from client side,this driver get executed and browser is opening in server.The website containing captcha's ,so it must open in client side.Is there any option for that?Thank you for you help...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium webdriver can be used in different languages. 
I can give you an example.

A web application is developed by using python in back-end and front-end is built up with html and a interpreted programming language like javascript. If we use selenium webdriver with python then browser opens at server side. and if we use selenium with javascript then browser opens at client side.